# python igraph all_st_mincuts returning 0 cuts

Tags: python, graph, python-2.7, igraph, max-flow

I'm using python igraph's all_st_mincuts function to cut a non-planar, bidirectional graph with ~3000 vertices and ~9000 edges. Depending on what capacities I assign to the edges, sometimes all_st_mincuts returns 0 cuts! It doesn't seem possible to me that a graph can have no minimum s-t cuts. What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Without _complete_ code that reproduces the problem, very hard to say. Maybe a bug, but maybe you made a mistake. Maybe s=t, and then there is no cut indeed.

Comment: This does not help much, sorry. This is hundreds of different files. What to run here? How to reproduce the problem? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example This is about R, but most of it applies to Python, too.